# Obtener valor de columna en fila actual-tabla jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Tengo una *DataTable* con datos. En la misma estoy tratando de hacer *click* en una celda de X fila la cual me va a permitir cambiar ese dato. Una vez que le de ENTER quiero capturar el ID (que viene siendo la primera columna de **esa** fila):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En rojo es lo que que cambio
- En azul es el valor que quiero obtener despues de cambiar el 50

El *input* donde **edito** se genera dinámicamente al darle click a las celdas de la penultima columna:

```
$('#tablaStandard tbody').on('click', '.cantidadX', async function() {
  if (!$('#tablaStandard').hasClass("editing")) {
    $('#tablaStandard').addClass("editing");
    var thisCell = table.cell(this);
    console.log(thisCell);
    thisCell.data($('<input class="form-control cantidadEditOrden" type="number" value="' + thisCell.data() + '" name="number">').prop("outerHTML"));
  }
});
```

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

```
$('#tablaStandard tbody').on("keypress", ".cantidadEditOrden", (e) => {

  if (e.which == 13) {

    console.log($('#tablaStandard tr').closest("tr").find("td:first-child").html());
    console.log($('#tablaStandard tr').closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(0)").html());
    console.log($('#tablaStandard tr').find("td:eq(0)").html());
    var first_td = $('#tableID tbody tr').closest("tr") // Finds the closest <tr> 
      .find("td:first") // Finds the first <td>
      .text(); // Gets its text. 
    console.log(first_td);
    console.log($('#tableID tbody').closest("tr").find("td:first"));
    console.log($('#tableID tbody tr').closest("tr").find("td").text());
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').children());
    table.cell($(".cantidadEditOrden").parents('td')).data($(".cantidadEditOrden").val());
    $('#tablaStandard').removeClass("editing");

  }

});
```

Pero no me devuelve lo que requiero, solo esta linea:

```
console.log($('#tablaStandard tr').closest("tr").find("td:first-child").html());
```

Me esta devolviendo valor, pero me devuelve la primera coincidencia de la tabla, lo cual esta mal ya que necesito la de la fila actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al tratar de traer el Indice de la DataTable, el mismo me devuelve undefined:

```
 var rowindex = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).index();
 console.log("Index ", rowindex);
 var id_celda = table.cell(rowindex, 0).data.id;
 console.log("Valor ", id_celda);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que necesito cambiar para poder obtener el valor de la fila donde haga la modificación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que estamos hablando de **datatables**, y que este script tiene sus propios métodos para calcular estas cosas, y suponiendo que la tabla esté asignada a la variable `table` (tal como parece por tu código) podrias hacer lo siguiente, calculando primero en que fila estas, gracias a la clase `cantidadEditOrden`:

```javascript
var rowindex = table.row($(".cantidadEditOrden").parents('tr')).index();
```

y luego asignando el valor de la primera columna (celda) de dicha fila a una variable:

```javascript
var id_celda = table.cell(rowindex, 0).data();
```

y después ya puedes trabajar con ella para lo que necesites.

### Otra solución (parecida)

```javascript
var data = table.row($(".cantidadEditOrden").parents('tr')).data();
var id_celda = data[0];
```

### Más soluciones

Analizando el porque mis anteriores ediciones de esta respuesta no funcionaban bien con el **this**, me acabo de dar cuenta que usas una sintaxis de flecha en esta línea:

```
$('#tablaStandard tbody').on("keypress", ".cantidadEditOrden", (e) => {
```

lo cual impide el uso de **this** dentro de la función, tal como esta documentado en sus [limitaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Si cambias eso por una función normal:

```
$('#tablaStandard tbody').on("keypress", ".cantidadEditOrden", function (e) {
```

entonces sí que funcionan mis anteriores ediciones de esta respuesta. Es decir, esto funcionaría:

```
var rowindex = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).index();
var id_celda = table.cell(rowindex, 0).data();
```

y esto también:

```
var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
var id_celda = data[0];
```

Agrego finalmente esto en la respuesta para dejar constancia de ello.

Comment: Al tratar de "mostrar" en la consola el valor de index, este viene vacio, por lo tanto la segunda linea (el "id_celda") no me trae nada, edito la pregunta para mostrar los datos que arroja

Comment: Perdón, me confundí y pense que el click era sobre la fila y no el botón. Prueba la actualización de la respuesta que acabo de poner.

Comment: nuevamente error estimado, al tratar de hacer el "table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();" data es undefined por tanto data[0 da error

Comment: ale, esta es la definitiva... esto me pasa por leerme en diagonal las preguntas, je :-)  (debes ponerlo antes de reasignar el valor con table.cell, claro)

Comment: Excelente, ahora si resulto, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada, gracias a tí, me has dado una idea para mejorar mi uso de datatables en lo relativo a la edición de las celdas :-)   Como decia antes, me miré la pregunta de reojo solamente pero al revisarla bien me gustó como lo haces :-)

Comment: @Baker1562 He actualizado mi respuesta con más soluciones, para que lo sepas por si quieres modificar tu código, y para que entiendas el porque el **this** no funcionaba bien

Comment: Muchas gracias, tambien me sirve esto, gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias en tu `input` en el que escribes, ponerle un atributo de dataset, digamos data-id='tuId' y en keypess hacer $(this).data('id') para obtenerlo, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$("body").on("keypress", ".changedValue", function(e){
        if (e.which == 13){
            let id = $(this).data('id'); 
            let value = $(this).val();
            console.log(`Value: ${this.value} ID: ${id}`);
        }
        
    })
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" class="changedValue" data-id="1" />
<input type="text" value="" class="changedValue" data-id="2" />
<input type="text" value="" class="changedValue" data-id="3" />
<input type="text" value="" class="changedValue" data-id="4" />
<input type="text" value="" class="changedValue" data-id="5" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Asi podrias de forma mas directa sin pasar por tanto selector de busqueda, tambien lo puedes aplicar sobre el `tr`

Comment: El problema es que ese input se genera dinamicamente, por lo que al generarlo tampoco se ese valor en ese momento, edite la pregunta para agregar esa parte del codigo.